# Confusion about routing in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 code, items is a resource (I created a database migration for items with rails generate model item column1:string ...). I have created a controller, items_controller, with a method htmlupdates in it. I do an ajax call with

```
url: '/items/htmlupdates'
```

My code works fine when I put the following line in my config/routes.rb

```
get 'items/htmlupdates' => 'items#htmlupdates'
```

but the code doesn't work when I put the following in config/routes.rb

```
resources :items, only: [:new, :htmlupdates, :create]
```

In the terminal log I receive the error message:

```
Started GET "/items/htmlupdates?_12345678..." for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-15 10:47:54 -0700
Processing by ItemsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"_"=>12345678...", "id"=>"grades"}
```

Why does it think that I'm trying to display the htmlupdate row in items table? What is the correct format for url in the ajax call?
Thanks.

Comment: You have several typos in your question. I can't tell if you just typed it wrong in here or if the errors you're getting are due to that.

Comment: Sorry about the typos, the errors are not due to typos.

Comment: So did you really use `resources items, only[:new, :htmlupdates, :create]` instead of `resources :items, :only => [:new, :htmlupdates, :create]`?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Could you attempt to simplify and use better English.

Comment: Sorry about the typo again, I have used resources :items, only: [:new, :htmlupdates, :create] but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails resources are based on the seven RESTful actions `index`, `show`, `new`, `edit`, `create`, `update` and `destroy`, which are mapped to HTTP verbs GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and PATCH.

You can't use the `resource` command to create custom routes that are outside of these actions. For custom routes, use:

```
get 'items/htmlupdates', :to => 'items#htmlupdates'
```

For more info, take a look at the routing documentation at [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).